# Approach to create crypto price alert system in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cryptography, alert

I want to create a alert system in nodejs, but the problem is how can I make it real time.
assuming every user has different price threshold.
and assuming having atleast 1000 users and 1000 alerts.

I know nodejs run asyncronouslty.

my question is how to make a function or approach that run individually for each user.

I tried using setInterval and run function every secong which check active alert but it is not real time.

Comment: You should look into WebSockets and the [WebSocket APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) in browsers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.